# accessing values in subgroups in html code

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I want the output as "Hindi", "English". I am able to get "Hindi", but I am facing difficulty with outputting "English"

Input:

```
<td class="_480u">
<div class="clearfix">
<div><a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=112969428713061" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Hindi/112969428713061">Hindi</a> and 
      <a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=106059522759137" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/English/106059522759137">English</a></div></div></td>
```

Code I tried:

```
>>> details.find('a',{'class':''}).string
u'Hindi'

s = details.findAll('a',{'class':''})
s1 = len(s)
list2 = []
if s1 >= 1:
   for j in range(0,s1):
      lang = s[j].find('a',{'class':''}).string.strip()
      list2.append(lang)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#220>", line 9, in <module>
    lang = s[j].find('a',{'class':''}).string.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'


>>> s
[<a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=112969428713061" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Hindi/112969428713061">Hindi</a>, <a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=106059522759137" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/English/106059522759137">English</a>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's exact HTML, that won't be changed you can use this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<td class="_480u">\
<div class="clearfix">\
<div><a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=112969428713061" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Hindi/112969428713061">Hindi</a> and \
      <a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=106059522759137" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/English/106059522759137">English</a></div></div></td>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.find('a',{'class':''}).string
print soup.find('a',{'class':''}).nextSibling.nextSibling.string
```

Output:

```
Hindi
English
```

---

Or you can do it like this (if your working only with the HTML that you posted in the question):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<td class="_480u">\
<div class="clearfix">\
<div><a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=112969428713061" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Hindi/112969428713061">Hindi</a> and \
      <a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=106059522759137" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/English/106059522759137">English</a></div></div></td>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
lang = soup.findAll('a', href = True)
for i in lang:
    print i.string
```

Output:

```
Hindi
English
```

Comment: I get "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" using the second approach